# Understanding statistical independence of events using a relative frequency interpretation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

This is what I've read in my textbook:

"If $n_A$ and $n_B$ are the number of times the independent events $A$ and $B$ have occurred, then we expect that the ratio $\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}$ (num. of times the intersection occurs over times $A$ occurs) also tends to $P(B)$" !!

I really don't understand how the author came to this conclusion! Why do we expect the ratio to tend to $P(B)$ if the events are independent??!

I know that $P(B|A)=P(B)$ but I want an interpretation. Moreover, the author has not yet mentioned conditional probability when he talks about independence.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

The book: Probability and Statistics - T.T. Soong

**Edit 1**: The rest of the author's argument is:

$\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}=P(B)=\frac{n_B}{n}$
,which gives: $\frac{n_{AB}}{n}=(\frac{n_{A}}{n})(\frac{n_{B}}{n})$

And the author then concludes that:

$P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$

So the author is using the argument to justify the equation above and we can't use it in the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be the total number of draws. Then by definition:
$$\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}=\frac{n_{AB}/N}{n_A/N}=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A)}=P(B).$$

Note that the usual definition of conditional probability has been circumvented by the law of independence: $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I just added!

Comment: @Ali: I'm following along in your book here: http://vfu.bg/en/e-Learning/Math--Soong_Fundamentals_of_probability_and_statistics_for_engineers.pdf

Section 2.3. It looks like the author is being handwavy and using the "intuition" that "the nonoccurance of A doesn't affect the nonoccurance of B", which allows them to conclude $n_{AB}/n_A$ tends to $P(B)$. I.E. in the space where $A$ has occured (represented by $n_A$), it should not affect the probability of $B$.

Comment: When you read the book, doesn't it seem like the equality $\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}=P(B)=\frac{n_B}{n}$ kind of comes out of the blue?
Could you please explain a little further how "the nonoccurance of A doesn't affect the nonoccurance of B" helps us in concluding that $\frac{n_{AB}}{n_A}=P(B)$?

Comment: @Ali: I agree, that's why the author uses the word "intuition." Basically, he's saying that if you observe occurances of $A$, they should not influence the occurrance of $B$. In this case we're subsetting to all events where $A$ has occurred, and our "intuition" of independence should suggest that $B$ occuring within these events has the same probability as if we were looking over all events that include and don't include $A$ occurring.